# What is the name of this chip on Arduino Mega ? I am not finding its datasheet 56 TI MSP?

Tags: arduino

What is the function of this ci in the arduino mega circuit, I need to describe it and I didn’t get the datasheet, see the component photo below.

[IC image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUu9E.png)

Comment: Hi @ vrdevfr, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider posting this question on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for advice, I learned StackExchange :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's comparator. If u connect both usb-b suply and micro-usb, comparator choose what input to use as power suply.